# Newton method in C

Tags: c, numerical-methods

Im working on 3D simulation of planet movement. And I need to solve equation

> np*t = x - e*sin(x)

In moment of solving i know values of np, t and e.
For every planet np (angle speed) and e ( eccentricity of planet orbit).
So I need to solve that equation for every moment in time to know coordinates of planet. 
t goes from 1 to some number lets say 50.

I chose newton method, with first value of iteration array np*t, and do 10 iterations. 
I check results of code with wolframalpha.
So here is problem. For 50 values of t (from 1 to 50) I get almost all correct values. three-four results are mistaken for max 1 (its acceptable)  but for value 12, (12*04 = x - 11*sin(x) , with entered paramaters) i get really big mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

/* np*t = E - e*sin(E)*/
/* 0 = E - e*sin(E) - np*t */

double f(double np, double t, double e, double E){
  return E - e*sin(E) - np*t;
}

double f_prim(double np, double t, double e, double E){
  return 1.0 - e*cos(E);
}

double newton(double np, double t, double e){
  double xk = np*t, xk1;
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 10){
    xk1 = xk - f(np, t, e, xk)/f_prim(np,t,e,xk);
    xk = xk1;
    i++;
  }
  return xk1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int i=12;
  for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    printf("Solution %d %.5f \n", i, newton(0.4,1.0*i,11.0));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And return value of program for 12 is

> Solution 12 41.00415

And the biggest solution of equation is 14,6

Can someone tell me why I have that big mistake for 12, and how to solve it

EDIT:
Fixed number of iterations is for debug purposes (its same result for 100 iterations too :( )

EDIT2:
I misplaced order of values in call of my newton method. So e*sin(x) wasn't between -.95 and .95 as it should be, but was much bigger, so I get really small derivative which made mistake with division.

Comment: You can see what happends if you plot the results. At least export to excel or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's method can be very sensitive to the choice of the initial value for the iteration. In this case the initial value 4.8 makes the derivative of the function very small . Division by a very value causes the method to over-shoot on the first iteration:

> x<sub>1</sub> = 4.8 - (4.8 - 11 sin(4.8) - 4.8) / (1 - 11 cos(4.8)) = −287.321177325

This function goes up and down a lot, so the method will probably never converge with this initial value. You can apply one of a number of tricks to choose a better one:

- Perturb the initial value by a random number if the method doesn't begin converging in a few iterations
- Use [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to bracket the root until you get "sufficiently close" and then use Newton's method
- Pick three points close to each other, fit a 2nd degree polynomial to them, and use one of its roots as the initial value.

Comment: Well, I found where I had problem. It happened that I enter in my function parameters in incorrect order, so i get problematic function for newton (small derivative). e it should be between 0 and 0.95 (as eccentricity of ellipse from circle, and in my code it was 11 (what np should be).

When correct values are initialized I have that np*t + e*sin(x) = x , where e*sin(x) couldnt be greater than 0.95 by absolute value so interval where im gonna look for root is  np*t +- 1. :)

Comment: That makes sense, with those parameters a unique solution is ensured.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple roots to an equation, there's no way to be sure which root you get from the Newton method. Since you're using trig functions, you might have an infinite number of roots to the equation (edited to add 'might', from comments, the equation in the question has a finite number of roots).

I'd be tempted to use the previous result for the initial value of xk rather than np*t.

You could show the calculations graphically to verify the correct root is being determined.

But this is probably best asked over on the maths stack exchange site.

Comment: Do you mean that at t=12 you get a big mistake regardless of the number of iterations? From then on, the remaining values are incorrect?

Comment: @Tarik: It's not a mistake, it's just heading towards a root you weren't expecting. Try iterating the algorithm using a pen and paper and a function like sin(x) to see what's going on and you'll see how the algorithm can sometimes find roots you weren't expecting. If the tangent at the initial estimate point is nearly horizontal, then the next guess could be several cycles away. In fact, picking a suitable starting point, the algorithm could move an integer number of times the frequency in one direction each step, and so never find a root.

Comment: How infinite number of roots? If equation is np*t = x - e*sin(x) and all except x (in given equation which Im trying to find roots) e*sin(x) couldnt go over e, and if I have np*t = x - e*sin(x), x in some moment will go over e and it cant be infinite solutions, because of -.

Comment: @Steva: sin(x) is circular, i.e. sin(x)==sin(x+tau), there are many solutions to that. There may be more than one root in your equation, I'm not really a maths person so I could be wrong.

Comment: sin(x) as trigonometric function have infinite solutions, because its periodic function. However if x is unknown, and equation is y = x - sin(x), where y is some constant, then our equation does not have infinite set of solutions. It can be more than one, but it cant be infinite, because with changing of sin(x) we change x as well. If equation is y = z - sin(x), where y,z is constants than we will have  infinite set of solutions.